# Как правильно наследовать модуль dektrium/yii2-user?

Tags: php, yii2, наследование

Всем привет!
Использую модуль Yii2-user. Нужно было сделать так, чтобы при входе неавторизованного пользователя не было никакого меню, а только форма ввода логина и пароля. Для этого сделал следующие вещи.
Создал модуль users.

```
namespace app\modules\users;

class Module extends \dektrium\user\Module
{
    public $controllerMap = [
        'admin'    => 'dektrium\user\controllers\AdminController',
        'registration' => 'dektrium\user\controllers\RegistrationController',
        'security'     => 'app\modules\users\controllers\SecurityController',// Переопределенный контроллер
        'recovery'     => 'dektrium\user\controllers\RecoveryController',
        'settings'     => 'dektrium\user\controllers\SettingsController',
        'profile'      => 'dektrium\user\controllers\ProfileController',
    ];
}
```

В котором переопределил контроллер SecurityController на свой

```
namespace app\modules\users\controllers;

use dektrium\user\controllers\SecurityController as BaseSecurityController;

class SecurityController extends BaseSecurityController
{
    public function actionLogin()
    {
        $this->layout = 'main-login';
        return parent::actionLogin();
    }
}
```

В своем модуле переопределил основную вьюху, всю выводить не буду, только покажу проблемный участок.

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <?= Html::a(
                    Yii::t('user', 'Forgot password?'),
                    ['/user/recovery/request']
                ) ?>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Как видно, ссылка ведет на '**/user/recovery/request**', но при нажатии на ссылку попадаю на '**/user/forgot**', что приводит к 404 ошибке.
Как я понял это происходит по той причине, что у самого модуля dektrium/yii2-user прописано

```
public $urlRules = [
        '<id:\d+>'                               => 'profile/show',
        '<action:(login|logout|auth)>'           => 'security/<action>',
        '<action:(register|resend)>'             => 'registration/<action>',
        'confirm/<id:\d+>/<code:[A-Za-z0-9_-]+>' => 'registration/confirm',
        'forgot'                                 => 'recovery/request',// Тут правило которое меняет маршрут
        'recover/<id:\d+>/<code:[A-Za-z0-9_-]+>' => 'recovery/reset',
        'settings/<action:\w+>'                  => 'settings/<action>'
    ];
```

Теперь вопрос: как правильно исправить эту ситуацию, чтобы не возникала ошибка 404?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В конфиге переопределите пути для вашего контроллера и views.

```
'components' => [
...
        'view' => [
            'theme' => [
                'pathMap' => [
                    '@dektrium/user/views' => '@app/modules/users/views',
                ],
            ],
        ],
...
]

'modules' => [
...
        'user' => [
            'controllerMap' => [
                'security' => 'app\modules\users\controllers\SecurityController',
            ],
        ],
...
]
```